# Quando devo criar uma constraint como DEFERRED?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, chave-estrangeira, constraint

Até onde eu sei, criar uma constraint (como uma chave estrangeira ou um check) como DEFERRED faz com que ela só seja validada no final da transação.

Pra que isto é usado? E quando não deve ser usado?

Answer (score 0):

Uma boa prática com DEFERRED encontra aplicação na movimentação de grandes volumes de dados. Quando a validação da *constraint* ocorre somente no COMMIT, geralmente o *chunk* (volumes muito grandes devem ser divididos em *chunks*) é gravado mais rapidamente.

Outra utilização possível seria uma movimentação de chaves. Nesses casos, não é possível alterar chaves primárias ou estrangeiras sem postergar ou desabilitar as *constraints*.